# a question about install qr_flutter in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
```

/Users/duzengjie/app/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Because qr depends on qr_flutter ^4.1.0 which depends on qr ^3.0.1, qr ^3.0.1 is required.
So, because qr is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1

What should I do about this

I added qr But I still can't.

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  qr: ^3.1.0
```

/Users/duzengjie/app/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Error on line 13, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
╷
13 │   qr: ^3.1.0
│   ^^
╵
Process finished with exit code 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project name (`qr`) conflicts with the `qr` package from pub.dev. Rename your project name to something else.

Comment: Thank you.The problem is the project name